# Python : Unable to write image file after reading image from ACCESS db

Tags: python, image, tkinter

```
enter code here
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox
from . import dbqueries
from . import db, dbqueries
def saveImages(userid):
    fname = userid + "_A"
    images = dbqueries.selectImages(userid)// OLE object from MS access DB
    f = images[0] # Binary data
    newfile = open(fname + ".jpg", 'w+')
    for line in f:
        newfile.write(str(line))
    print(os.getcwd())
    #messagebox.showinfo("profile image saved", " saved")
    newfile.close()
```

When I open the newfile from directory receiving error "It looks like we do not support file format".
I've tried encoding decoding using BASE64 package, no luck.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CP7IG.jpg)

Comment: Please type the error into the body of the message instead of just including an image.

Comment: Actually I'm not getting any error . It's most likely endode/decode issue.